# Helicopter auto-hover problem

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, physics

We are working on a helicopter game, and encountered a rather difficult problem:

For sake of simplicity, let's consider this to be a one-dimensional problem.

I have a helicopter traveling at speed $V$ and an arbitrary pitch angle $A$.
The acceleration of the helicopter is defined as thrust $t$ and mass $m$ as $\frac{t \cdot \cos(A)}{m}$.

The pitch rate has a max of `dAMAX`, and a maximum rate of change of `ddAMAX`.
Also there's simplified air drag $R = \frac{1}{2}v^2 \cdot \text{dragCoefficient}$, although that might be a needless complication for this problem.

So the goal is to achieve $V=0$ and $A=0$ simultaneously in the least amount of time as possible.

Made a little animation to show the approximate scenario:
[hover sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cO7FY.gif)

Comment: This is a vastly under-constrained problem.  You can achieve the end result in infinitely many ways.

Comment: Terribly sorry, forgot to mention that this is for a game, hence the limited scope of variables.

Comment: What does a game have to do with anything?  There are still infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork forgive me, I edited the post to include a key condition, which is to achieve V=0 and A=0 in as little time as possible.

Comment: Are you sure you want $A=0$ rather than $A=\frac\pi 2$ in the end? (or that you have $\cos$ and not $\sin$ in the acceleration formula)

Comment: Yes, this should definitely be $\sin$ rather than $\cos$.

Comment: Questions: It's unclear what you mean by "pitch rate." Is this the time derivative of the pitch angle? In that case, what is the "maximum rate of change"? Are you fixing the initial value of the pitch angle $A$, or can it be whatever we want?

Comment: @SergeyKabanchenko  How are you modelling the other forces on the helicopter? What is the quantity $t\cos A /m$? Is this supposed to be an acceleration? In this case the thrust $t$ has to be a force- not an acceleration as you seem to imply.

Comment: @SergeyKabanchenko  Finally, is there some torque on the helicopter that slows down the pitch angle variation? Or does it come solely from the drag force itself?

Comment: @fedja you are correct, Pi/2 is a more appropriate final angle.

Comment: @JohnBarber Correct, pitch rate is the derivative of pitch angle. We could ignore maximum rate of change if it makes the problem easier (and I suspect it does). It's useful for player input, not critical for AI input however. 
Initial values are out of our control, since the helicopter can be at any attitude/speed/pitch rate etc when the player initiates the auto hover

Comment: @DinosaurEgg well, if F=ma, a = f/m. In this case, force is t cos A. So I *think* i'm correct there?
There is a torque, and it comes from a constant maximum torque value * AI input in this case. Hope this makes sense

Comment: @SergeyKabanchenko I guess I'm still confused about the difference between `dAMAX` and `ddAMAX`. Did you mean to specify a _maximum pitch angle_ and a _maximum rate of change of pitch angle_? Also, wouldn't it be slightly simpler to define your angle $A$ with respect to the vertical, so that the final condition would have everything at $0$?

Comment: Anyway, the optimal strategy is to first drop the pitch angle to zero forward acceleration as fast as you can, then move it towards the backward acceleration as fast as you can then, perhaps, keep it at the maximal backward acceleration for a while (if the initial speed was high), then move it to zero acceleration as fast as you can. The exact computation depends on the drag, etc., but this is the general idea. Also you may want to adjust your formulae to make the vertical displacement correct: you, probably, want a nice horizontal flight, not jumping up and down...